# Sencha Ext JS ArrayStore in Grid Empty

Tags: javascript, extjs

Good Morning,

I am brand new to Sencha EXT JS, like literately this is my first day. I have created a small application that creates a Grid inside a panel and then fills the grid with some data form an ArrayStore (hardcoded). The application runs fine but I get three empty entries in the grid and no data. Any idea's?

```
Ext.application({
name   : 'MyApp',

launch : function() {

Ext.onReady(function () {
    var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({ idProperty: 'storeTest', autoDestroy: true, storeId: 'myStore',idIndex: 0, fields: [{name: 'name', type: 'string'},{name: 'age', type: 'int'},]});

    var myData = [
        ['Person1',31],
        ['Person2',30],
        ['Person3',6]
    ];

    store.loadData(myData);

    var resultsPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'Results',
        width: 1000,
        height: 400,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout: { type: 'hbox', align: 'stretch', padding: 5 },
        items: [{ xtype: 'grid', columns: [{header: 'Name'}, { header: 'Age' }], store: store, flex: 1 },
        { xtype: 'splitter' },
        { title: 'Details', bodyPadding: 5, items: [{ fieldLabel: 'Data item', xtype: 'textfield'}], flex: 2 }]
    });
});
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the dataIndex property for each columns:

```
[{ xtype: 'grid', columns: [{header: 'Name',dataIndex: 'name'}, { header: 'Age',dataIndex: 'age' }], store: store, flex: 1 },
```